# Efficiently counting correctly ranked pairs

Tags: algorithms

**The problem:**

Given a set of measurements $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$ and corresponding labels $y_1 <= y_2 <= ... <= y_n$ that designate the desired ranking, count the number of pairs that are actually ranked correctly by $x$. In other words, compute

$$
R((x_k, y_k)_{k=1}^n) = \sum_{i \in 1,...,n-1} \sum_{j \in i+1, ..., n} I(x_i < x_j)I(y_i < y_j)
$$

where $I$ is the indicator function that returns 1 if the condition is true and 0 otherwise. Note that ties (either in $x$ or in $y$) do not contribute towards the overall tally.

**Implementation:**

The most straightforward implementation is a doubly-nested `for` loop that iterates over all $n(n-1)/2$ possible pairs and increments a counter when the ranking condition is satisfied. This implementation has quadratic complexity.

It seems that there is an inherent structure to the problem. If we already computed $\sum_{i < k} I(x_i < x_k)I(y_i < y_k)$ for a given $k$, then we should be able to reuse it for any other $l$ that satisfies $x_k < x_l$ and $y_k < y_l$.

Would anybody be able to point me towards the best way to take advantage of the above observation and improve on the quadratic complexity? Intuitively, I feel like there may be a way to get it down to $O(n*log(n))$ with an appropriate binary data structure, but I can't quite place my finger on the right one.

Comment: Google things like "count inversions". They should mention a merge-sort-based algorithm for a very similar problem.

Comment: Aha! This is the keyword I was looking for. Thank you, @Dmitry